# Are graphic cards using the Map-Reduce model when performing typical gaming rendering

Tags: parallel-computing, graphics, mapreduce

I know that the Map-Reduce model is a common model of parallel computation, perhaps some sort of standard way(?). I also know that graphic cards are specifically built for parallel computation. However when reading about the graphic pipeline I am not sure if there is a point at which the Map Reduce model is used. If not, what kind of parallel computations (just the general model of them so I could read more about it) are done during the typical rendering process of modern graphics cards? If it is used, where would that be on the below pipeline?

[image: Programmable 3D-Pipeline public domain]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This model isn't appropriate for rendering games, so it's not used in game engines. However, it can be implemented on GPUs. F.e. if you are going to implement Spark / relational algebra on GPUs, it may be a part of implementation.